# Soundcloud API, PHP, and OAuth

Tags: php, xml, api, oauth, soundcloud

I'm building a site, and I need to query my last two tracks from my soundcloud account and display them on my page.
I've read the Soundcloud API documentation but it seems obscure and far from my reach.
I've installed the PHP library for using the API and Oauth, and set up my SoundCloud application to get my Consumer Keys, but I can't start the OAuth session.

I'm using this [library](http://wiki.github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud/getting-started).

I need to retrieve the last 2 tracks from my Soundcloud account. After I require the files from the library (soundcloud.php and oauth.php) I need to set four parameters: $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $callback_url, $tmp_path.

I already have my keys and my writable cache folder. I don't know what's my callback url. In addition, I must say I can't find any working example code, so I can not even start to write anything. So blocked!

Is there any way to automatize the OAuth process without invoking another window, so my OAuth Token is requested in my PHP script?.

I was wondering if maybe you could hand me some sample code for doing this.
That would be great!!

Comment: Can you give some more information? What do you expect, and what do you get in stead? Maybe some code sample.

Comment: @Ikke Hi! Thanks for answering so fast. I need to retrieve the last 2 tracks from my Soundcloud account. After I require the files from the library (soundcloud.php and oauth.php) I need to set four parameters: $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $callback_url, $tmp_path. I already have my keys and my writable cache folder. I don't know what's my callback url.

In addition, I must say I can't find any example code, so I can not even start to write anything. So blocked!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add this to the question to improve the question.

Comment: $callback_url is the url of your webpage. For instance, mine is http://localhost/soundcloud, as thats where my code is. I'm working on something similar at the moment, so I might be able to assist better in a bit!

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful to you. After logging in, it embeds my favourite tracks into the page.
You could change $favs to loads your own songs instead of your favourites instead.

Also note, my config.php includes my consumer_key, consumer_secret and my callback_url.

`$callback_url = 'http://localhost/soundcloud';`

You want it to equal the place where your php script is.

```
<?php
  require_once ('php-soundcloud/mptre-php-soundcloud-644bb0e/oauth.php');
  require_once ('php-soundcloud/mptre-php-soundcloud-644bb0e/soundcloud.php');
  require_once ('config.php');

session_start();

// Clear the session i.e delete all stored tokens.
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
}

// Variables used for verifying the status of the "OAuth dance".
$oauth_token = (isset($_GET['oauth_verifier']))
    ? $_GET['oauth_verifier']
    : ((isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) ? $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] : NULL);
$oauth_request_token = (isset($_SESSION['oauth_request_token']))
    ? $_SESSION['oauth_request_token']
    : NULL;
$oauth_request_token_secret = (isset($_SESSION['oauth_request_token_secret']))
    ? $_SESSION['oauth_request_token_secret']
    : NULL;

if (isset($oauth_token) && isset($oauth_request_token) && isset($oauth_request_token_secret)) {
    // Retreive access tokens if missing.
    if (!isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']) && !isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret'])) {
        $soundcloud = new Soundcloud(
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret,
            $_SESSION['oauth_request_token'],
            $_SESSION['oauth_request_token_secret']
        );
        $token = $soundcloud->get_access_token($oauth_token);
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret'] = $token['oauth_token_secret'];
    }

    // Construct a fully authicated connection with SoundCloud.
    $soundcloud = new Soundcloud(
        $consumer_key,
        $consumer_secret,
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'],
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret']
    );

    // Get basic info about the authicated visitor.
    $me = $soundcloud->request('me');
    $me = new SimpleXMLElement($me);
    $me = get_object_vars($me);

    // Get some embedding code for favs
    $favs = $soundcloud->request('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/'.$me['id'].'/favorites/');
    $favs = new SimpleXMLElement($favs);

} else {
    // This is the first step in the "OAuth dance" where we ask the visitior to authicate himself.
    $soundcloud = new Soundcloud($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $token = $soundcloud->get_request_token($callback_url);

    $_SESSION['oauth_request_token'] = $token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_request_token_secret'] = $token['oauth_token_secret'];

    $login = $soundcloud->get_authorize_url($token['oauth_token']);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SoundCloud PHP API Wrapper</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Anton Lindqvist" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/reset/reset-min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <?php if (isset($me)): ?>
                <a class="logout" href="?logout=true">logout</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div id="header">
                <h1>SoundCloud PHP API Wrapper</h1>
            </div>
            <?php if (isset($login)): ?>
            <h2>What is this?</h2>
            <p>This is a basic demo</p>
            <h2>How to start?</h2>
            <p><a class="button" href="<?php echo $login; ?>">login with your SoundCloud account</a></p>
            <?php elseif (isset($me)): ?>
                <div id="profile">
                  <h2>
                    <a href="<?php echo $me['permalink-url']; ?>"><?php echo $me['permalink']; ?></a>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div id="favs">
                <?php
                  if (isset($favs)){

                    foreach($favs->track as $fav){
                        $permalink_url = $fav->{'permalink-url'};
                        $permalink_url = urlencode($permalink_url);

                        $f = simplexml_load_file('http://soundcloud.com/oembed?url='.$permalink_url);
                        echo $f->html;
                    }

                  } else {
                     echo "fail";
                  }
                ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also note, that I'm a php noob, using this api for the first time... so my abilities don't stretch past this for the moment. Most of this was "borrowed" from the demo that comes with the php wrapper library you're using.

Hope it helps though :)

ps. Not sure if there is a way to automatize the OAuth process without invoking another window yet.

Comment: Plus I've just noticed that login/logout requires 2 attempts before success :(